# The algebra of natural transformations of the n-th power tensor functor

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, multilinear-algebra, monoidal-categories, operads

Let $k$ be a $0$ characteristic field, $n$ an positive integer and $S_n$ the $n$-th symmetric group.

Let's work in the symmetric monoidal category of $k$-vector spaces and linear maps that we denote $Vect_k$. Let $T^{(n)}$ be the functor $[V \mapsto V^{\otimes n}]$ where $V^{\otimes n}$ is the $n$-th tensor power of $V$ and $[f\mapsto f^{\otimes n}]$ where $f^{\otimes n}$ is the $n$-th tensor power of $f$. I know there is a faithfull action of $S_n$ on $T^{(n)}$ i.e. there is an injection $S_n \hookrightarrow Nat(T^{(n)}, T^{(n)})$ where $Nat(T^{(n)},T^{(n)})$ is $k$-algebra of natural transformations form $T^{(n)}$ to its self. Because of this I have an injection of the algebra of the symmetric group in $Nat(T^{(n)},T^{(n)})$ i.e. $$ k[S_n] \hookrightarrow Nat(T^{(n)}, T^{(n)}).$$

My questions are :

1. Is this injection an isomorphism of $k$-algebras? or are there other natural transformations from $T^{(n)}$ to its self?
2. Does it have to do with the $Vect_k$ category or is it something more general about symmetric monoidal categories?
3. If the category is just braided can we say the same kind of things for $k[B_n]$ where $B_n$ is the braided group on $n$ strings?

I came across this by trying to prove that $k[S_n]$-modules are the same as homogeneous polynomial functors of degree $n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. This is a corollary of [Schur-Weyl duality](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/four-flavors-of-schur-weyl-duality/).
2. You need at least the additional assumption that your symmetric monoidal category is enriched over $k$-vector spaces. In general I don't see any reason to expect that the action of $k[S_n]$ is faithful; consider, for example, the special case where we only look at $1$-dimensional vector spaces.
3. Sometimes. The keyword to look up here is "quantum Schur-Weyl duality."

Comment: Is there a way, starting from $\phi \in Nat(T^{(n)},T^{(n)})$ to get the element of $k[S_n]$ ?

Comment: @anton: look at the action of $\phi$ on $V$ such that the action of $k[S_n]$ on $V^{\otimes n}$ is faithful, and compare it to the action of elements of $k[S_n]$. Not very satisfying, I admit.

Comment: Thanks ! I wouldn't want to be the copmputer that has to do that :) I was also wondering : Schur-Weyl seems to always be stated for algebraically closed fields, does that cause a problem here ?

Comment: @anton: the proof of Schur-Weyl duality in the blog post I link to above doesn't assume this, only that the characteristic is $0$.